# Expo + Firebase authentication (sign up) security issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, expo

In short: In GCP credentials can be restricted with application restriction and with API restriction, but Identity Toolkit API cannot be restricted on Expo mobile application.
-In web **both restrictions work**
-On android/iOS **API restriction works** but (as I have tested, correct me if I'm wrong) **application restrictions does not**

Now if using email/password authentication there is an issue.
There is a huge insecurity here as if anyone gets to know your API key (you define in initializeApp and so you connect to Firebase with and so use with Identity Toolkit API).
**They can only by knowing that key call Firebase Auth REST API "Sign up with email / password" from anywhere and create users for your project!!**

Am I wrong, missing something or can this be prevented somehow?

Things you can do to prevent this:

1. In "GCP>credentials>Identity Toolkit API" you can lower "Queries per minute" and "Queries per minute per user"
2. You can in "Firebase>Authentiction>Sign-in method>Manage sign-up quota" lower the quota from same IP address to minium (but does this help in case of android/iOS application?)

But there is no completely secure solution unless you can application restrict your API key as far as I know.

Comment: I have contacted Firebase support team to ask if there is any way to secure email/password authentication with API key that is not restricted with application restriction. I will update here their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following answer from Firebase support and since there has not been answers I will add this as correct answer for anyone looking solution for same thing or seeing this question.

> First of all, I would like to thank you for choosing Firebase to
> implement your application. I know that these kinds of situations
> could be frustrating, let's work together to provide the best solution
> for you.
>
> I have checked your case and I would recommend that you reinforce your
> Security Rules, because this is not a security risk, as long as you
> secure access to the data within your project correctly for your
> requirements, as it is mentioned in this external entry.
>
> We don’t have a way to know the origin of those emails, even if they
> were created by real users through your app, but if you identify fake
> accounts you can use Cloud Functions to delete all emails registered
> with that pattern using Auth triggers. Alternatively, you can delete
> the accounts after an established time without activity using Schedule
> Functions.
>
> Additionally, if you don’t want to have users on your application, you
> would probably need to use the Admin SDK and authenticate the
> application by service account instead.